# svn: update file in branch to a pre-branch revision

Tags: svn

I have the following scenario:

I made a branch of trunk at revision 100. I made some changes and now repository is up to revision 110. I now want to mess around, in my branch, with an old revision of some files (from r90). I may decide to modify these files, in which case I want to commit the changes to my branch.

How to do this? If I simply update the files in my branch to revision 90, svn deletes them because my branch didn't exist at that point. Can I somehow merge an old revision of trunk into a current branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you removed the file between 90 and 100.

Reverse the changes from the revision when you removed your file (which I assume is between 90 and 100). Usually in most svn gui nowadays, you might not see them unless you uncheck "stop on copy/rename" in tortoise svn for example. If you are doing it from the command line it should not bug you.

The command should be something like reverse-merging X (whichever revision you remove the file from svn, between 90 And 100) into current revision.